# Issue consecutive commands in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line, subprocess, command

i'm attempting call a set of commands (A,B,C) in python. These commands setup the ability to finally call command X. However when command X is called it acts as if the others have not been. I believe this is due to the fact they are being issued separately rather than concurrently in the same environment. Is there any way to issue them all to the same open command line using Python. Thanks!

For reference the real commands initialize the execution of an AutoSys command.

I've tried using os.sysetm(), same issue as subprocess.call

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("Command A", shell=True)
subprocess.call("Command B", shell=True)
subprocess.call("Command C", shell=True)
subprocess.call("Command X", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` call creates a **new** child process with a shell process, and that shell process is told to execute the command given. Then the shell process is torn down again and exits, taking along any environment variables with it.

If you must run them all in a single parent shell process, then you need to use shell syntax to do it. E.g. you could use `;` to separate commands:

```
subprocess.call("Command A; Command B; Command C; Command X", shell=True)
```

this runs the commands sequentially. It doesn't matter if any of the commands succeed or fail, as their exit status is not taken into account when running the next.

Exactly what syntax you can use to control how commands are combined depends on your platform. On POSIX systems (Mac OS X or Linux) `/bin/sh` is used, which means you can use [POSIX-compliant shell commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). On Windows it depends on what `COMSPEC` what shell environment is used. You can request a different shell executable by setting `executable`, e.g. `executable=/bin/bash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("Command A && Command B && Command C && Command X", shell=True)
```

This will call them one after the other in bash